# C# Status 200 with No Content in Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using this C# code:

```
httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
var priceHistoryResponse = await _httpclient.GetAsync(priceHistoryUrlParameters);

if (priceHistoryResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // Put the post response in a string named priceHistoryResponseContent
    var priceHistoryResponseContent = await priceHistoryResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    //  Convert the priceHistoryContent string to JSON format
    PriceHistory priceHistory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceHistory>(priceHistoryResponseContent);
}
```

The priceHistoryResponse is:

```
{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:{  Date: Sat, 01 Feb 2020 22:30:02 GMT  Connection: keep-alive  Host: api.tdameritrade.com  X-Forwarded-For: 10.152.4.23  X-Forwarded-Port: 9002  X-Forwarded-Proto: http  Authorization: Bearer roFzGtWR8xRppA7LlaZ280goscoXbGPwOfkxxxE  NS-Proxy-Client-IP: 99.11.242.43  thirdparty: true  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, accept, authorization, content-type  Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000  Content-Length: 0}}
```

Does this priceHistoryUrlParameters url look formatted correctly?

```
https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/AAPL/pricehistory/apikey=AMN%40AMER.OAUTHAP
```

I added the /apikey=AMN%40AMER.OAUTHAP

Comment: Typically, query parameters are not separated using "/" but they're started with "?" and each thereafter is separated using "&". However, this might still be valid... all depends on how the API is designed and what it expects. From your code, we're not able to answer that.

Comment: Url you provided gives out error code... poorly written api with 200 response and an error

Answer (score 0):

I changed the / to a ? . as suggested. It works now.